# Can I link my customer model to my user model?

Tags: python, django

I'm working an a django e-commerce website where a user has to be a customer. But when I create a new user, it assigns it to the the superuser not the new user and get this error:
`Exception Value:   User has no customer.`

But i can also go to my admin panel and re-assign the customer to the user.
[django admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c74Bn.png)

How can I fix this please?

My `customer model`

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`members/views.py` to create new user and customer

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from shop.models import Customer
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import CreateCustomerForm

# Create your views here.

class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('customer')

class CreateCustomerView(CreateView):
    form_class = CreateCustomerForm
    template_name = 'registration/customerProfile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My shop view

```
def shop(request):

    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'shop/shop.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Customer model has a one-to-one unique relationship with User models.
Use `contrib.auth.models.User`
Example:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='customer')
```

Other the other hand (Slightly out of the context of the question), you can edit the User model to add the customer

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

class CustomUser(User):
    # Add the column you want o add.

    # Use UserManager to get the create_user method, etc.
    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: It gives me this error `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'customer'.` after migrating

Comment: Easy way to solve this: check the query under `migrations` folder.
The default field is most likely to be wrong.

For reference, you can refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@stackpython/django-errors-solving-63e497cd560a)